# I really need help to fill the gaps on one statement in completion of a measure theorem´s proof (edited question)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ a measure space and $N =\{N' \in S : \mu(N')= 0 \}$ the $\sigma$-ring of $S$-measurable sets of measure zero. We define :

$S^*= \{(E\cup M_{1})-M_{2} : E\in S \text{ and } M_{1} \subset  N_{i} \text{ where } i=1,2 \}$

Prove the following:

(i) $F\in S^*$ if and only if $F=(E\cup M_{0})$ with  $E\in S$ with $M_{0}$ a subset of some $N_{0} \in N$ (Where not always  $E$ and$ M_{0}$ are unique$ )

My idea to proof this is seeing $F\in S^*$ ; we can see $F=\{ ((A \cup M_{1})- M_{2}\text{ where }A \in S\text{ and } M_{i}\subset N_{i}\in N\}$ ; and  $B= A- N_{2}$ and $ M_{0} =( M_{1}-M_{2})\cup  ((A\cap N_{2}) -M_{2})$  where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are in N so we only  need to prove that $F=B\cup M_{0}$ which i can not prove .Thanks i will aprecitate you to be helpful with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your argument looks right, to show $F = B\cup M_0$, from your definition,

$$F = (A-N_2) \cup (A\cap N_2 - M_2) \cup (M_1 - M_2).$$
If you look at the first two union, it is 
$$(A-N_2) \cup (A\cap N_2 - M_2) = (A-N_2)\cup (A\cap N_2) - M_2 = A - M_2$$
then it follows that 
$$F = (A-M_2) \cup (M_1 - M_2) = (A\cup M_1) - M_2.$$

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help!